# Original ubuntu password change fails

Tags: server, 20.04, system-installation, password

I am attempting to install ubuntu server 20.04 onto a Raspberry PI (in this second attempt using an SD created with Raspberry Pi Imager). I get to enter the initial user and password ubuntu/ubuntu it then asks for a new password -- I enter a password once and under SSH the putty session drops no message.  I move the PI to an HDMI keyboard setup and get almost the same response.  I enter the initial user and password ubuntu/ubuntu and it asks for the new password -- I have entered about a dozen different values.  The machine flashes an error message too fast to read and returns to the logon screen.  Over many iterations I believe the message being flashed is "Authentication token manipulation error".  I have sought ubuntu's password requirements and found nothing.  I have searched this error text and find example after example of people with a running system and no one having this problem on install.  I cannot remount drives or anything else as I have never been able to login to the system.  Does anyone have any idea what is going wrong?  Why is this message NOT being displayed on the screen so one can actually READ it before it disappears?

FYI the SSH logon attempts had the network connected.  When I move the PI to an HDMI display it has no network connection.  If either of those matter I have disclosed it.  I also tried ssh connection of the live system in an attempt to create a ZFS root install of Ubuntu Server 20.04 with what appears to be the same results.

Thanks in advance to anyone who tries to assist.

This installation is of the 64 bit version of Ubuntu Server 20.04 onto a Raspberry PI 3 with an non functional wireless communication.  Eventually when I get the appropriate heat sinks this installation is targeted for a Raspberry Pi 4B 8GB of ram.

This morning I used the Raspberry Pi Imager to flash the 32 bit version of Ubuntu 20.04 server (LTS) same problem with entering the new password.  Entry of the password.

The second time I tried to logon to the 32 bit version I figured out what was wrong.  I fell for the faint left go right fake in the initial logon process. After being told a password change was required I misread the prompt and entered the new password instead of the CURRENT password.  This is a user error.  Sorry for the confusion.  Please close this.

Comment: Entry of the current password is required before the new password.  This can be closed.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: After the prompt that indicates a password change was required; I failed to enter the current password before entering the new password.  I misread the current password prompt.  It was USER error and the user corrected his own error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was entering the wrong password.  I have corrected my own error.  Thanks for looking.